# Adhoc Distribution for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

Hello everyone , 
                 I just want to know that .. Is it necessary to add all the devices udid manually while  creating distribution provisioning profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's. You need to add the device, and then select it when you're going to generate the AD-HOC provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

I signed an app with a "AppStore" profile and the archived it and save for distribution. This works at the begining, but when i send the IPA to others peoples, they (most of them)cant install the app in their devices. Try it anyway.